# Turn off Tag Navigator in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper, navigator

I've looked everywhere on how to turn off the Tag Navigator at the bottom of my Visual Studio 2008 and can't any info!

Since installing ReSharper a group of us have come across a bug where it will reset your mouse cursor to 0,0 when you rollover a tag in the Tag Navigator and since I can't find any info on that bug I just want the Navigator to go away, but can't seem to even turn THAT off...

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer but a warning of a false answer.  I have this exact same problem and I was sent this link. After trying it out Visual Studio crashed and after it had recovered the tag bar was still there.

[Registry hack to "remove" the design/split/source bar](http://renaissauce.com/thoughts/visual-studio-2008-tip-remove-the-design-split-source-button-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

This should help to eliminate the mouse cursor reset issue in the Tag Navigator:

Open regedit and find the following key:

```
\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\HTML Editor
```

Modify the following entry:

```
ShowTagToolbar = -1
```

Then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Any ideias how to do it in Visual Studio 2010? This method doesn't work.